# Multiple choice form action depend on choice

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this [image]

Multiple choice form, the button goes to a certain page when clicked. However, I want it to run something specific when the page is reached. So if someone submits the form with Orc Camp selected, they would go through one set of code, but if Orc City was selected they would go through another.

I know how to do this in the same page (IF isset post etc) but I don't know how to link the button result to another page!

EXAMPLE

Orc Camp is selected, button is pressed and user goes to different page, lets call it battle.php

The page will echo "You have attacked Orc Camp" if Orc  Camp was selected.

If Orc Village was selected, it will again go to battle.php but will echo "You have attacked Orc Village"

Sorry if I haven't described the problem well enough

Comment: Well just get the value of the radiobutton.. And use a switch for the different options? Writing some code for every different option?

Comment: I know how they work, just not how to make the value of the radio button to carry on over to another page.

Comment: @Naruto Yeah I was looking at making a switch, but isn't the value dropped unless I save it? If I save it, how can it be recalled on a different page?

Comment: Since you are going to another page, I guess you are submitting a form... If you submit a form you can get a value again by using $_request or $_post.. You can use isset($_post) even when going to another page..

Comment: Ah, didn't know POST worked on pages other than the one that contains the form lol thanks, want to post it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a form like:

```
<form action="http://somesite.com/battle" method="POST">
```

OR

```
<form action="http://somesite.com/overview" method="POST">
```

All the values that are within a `<form></form>` tag are automatically saved in $_POST. An easy tip I use to see which values get passed is just use `var_dump($_POST)` to print all the data to the screen that was saved in $_POST.

Example form on battle.net:

```
<form action="http://somesite.com/battle" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="action" value="attack">Attack<br>
    <input type="radio" name="action" value="defend">Defend<br>
</form>
```

The action is now set to go to battle page, so now you just need to get the data on the battle page like:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']))
```

The only thing you need to do now, is add error handling and your logic etc.. to the battle page.